# Remove tailing ".0" from prices

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How I can remove ".0" from my Price number from my android studio app?

MyApp save orders in database, then user can place order, after that server app get the orders placed.
I'm also using Retrofit2.

I have double prices 2000.0. 
I want them without tailing 0, just 2000.

There are other sections with this problem, which I guess some guide about how to fix this part can help me to fix other parts.

Comment: Where/how would you ever see ".numbers"?

Comment: @Andreas means anything [.numbers => .21242] or anything like this. i just wanted to remove everything after [Dot].

Comment: By "remove", do you mean "truncate" (e.g. `4.7`  => `4`), or "round" (e.g. `4.7`  => `5`)?

Comment: none. i have simple numbers without 4.7 to round to 5 or truncate. my prices are like this (eg. `2000` , `5000` , `20000`) that's all nothing more. right now in top code, when i put `2000` price, app showing `2000.0` but i just want `2000`

Comment: So that covers the ".0", but if you never have any value with numbers after the decimal point, then why did you add ".numbers" to the question? More importantly, why did you use `double` and not `int` as the variable type, if you never need non-integer values? Or is it that you *might* have decimals? If so, do you want value *truncated* or *rounded*? You are contradicting yourself, so you should edit the question and ***clarify it!***

Comment: @Andreas well i'm creating this project base on a tutorial, and Instructor used double. and now i'm trying to fix it. if there's any idea please explain. right now i'm trying answers.

Comment: If instructor used `double`, then instructor might give you data with decimals, so you need to decide what should happen if that occurs. When writing code, you need to handle edge cases *as you write the code*. You cannot just say "we'll figure that out when/if it happens", because you'll likely not be there to fix the code when it does.

Comment: @Andreas so how i can use int instead of double? base on top code?

Comment: Replace `double` with `int`?

Comment: @Andreas well it's worked. please answer the question like other to confirm it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can solve this.
(Adding to Andreas comment)

Either use `int` instead of `double` altogether.

Or you can always cast your `double` value in `int`.

```
 double x = 1000.324;
 System.out.println("double  x = "+x);
 System.out.println("int     x = "+(int) x);
```

prints:

```
double  x = 1000.324
int     x = 1000
```

Comment: well i chose this answer because it was closer to my method. casting to int worked for me without any problem.

Comment: Cool. Also look at how `new DecimalFormat("#").format(2000.0);` works. It helps you play around with n digit after the decimal.

Comment: well i've searched about it. new decimal, i've understand now where i should use it now. this.

Comment: Try with some poc. And see where you require to print 200.01, 200.0123, 200.01235. All these can be printed with DecimalFormat. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for more explains. well the reason i'm searching for solutions here is, peoples experiences, methods, ideas and more... . thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use :

```
new DecimalFormat("#").format(2000.0);
```

The result is "2000" without decimals.

Comment: In the onbindviewholder of your drink adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do do remove the numbers after the decimal and it depends on what you are trying to achieve.

You can cast them to an Int or use `new DecimalFormat("#").format(value)` which will remove anything after the .

You can use the `Math.rint()` or `Math.round` functions this will round to the closest integer 3.99 will become 4

Comment: well i was coding this project base on a tutorial and i used math.round. u can saw in the code. i'm not experienced about how i should math.round to get closer or remove. where i should put [new DecimalFormat] ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply typecast your double value into int

> double percentageValue=200.0;
>
> System.out.println("remove value of after decimal point=="+(int)percentageValue);

and set value in android just like this:-

> txt_product_price.setText(String.valueOf((int)percentageValue));

Answer (score 0):

simply convert the `Double` value to `Integer`

```
Double x = 2000.0;

Integer y = (int) x;

Log.e("Integer format",String.valueOf(y));
```

and the Log is 2000